# Find a specific field on a site and the set it to "Required" in a EventReciever

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, spfield

I have created a EventReciever that will be activated when a site gets created. This site have a announcement webpart. When they click on "add announcement", newform.aspx pops up as a dialog and there is a field there that is called Expired I need to make it required.

.-.

How can I find that specific field and set it to Required in my EventReciever?

```
<!-- FieldName="Expires"
             FieldInternalName="Expires"
             FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
          -->
```

This is how I have progressed so far:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{

    if (properties.Feature.Parent is SPWeb)
    {
        var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
            var expiredDate = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Expires");
            expiredDate.Required = true;
            expiredDate.Update();

    }

}
```

Any kind of help or tips is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to work in some kind of a similar scenario as yours, however, i created an "Announcements" list and then added a web part that shows the content of that list. Then i used the code below to make the "Expires" field as "Required". I hope this will help:

```
        SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
        SPField field = list.Fields.GetField("Expires");
        if (field.Required == false)
        {
            field.Required = true;
            field.Update();
        }
```

Comment: What does SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Eliya"); do?

Comment: I have updated the answer where "ListName" is the name of the custom "Announcements" list that i created.

Comment: hmm I getting a error when I try to create a site, are you sure this code is not for site collection?

Comment: This eventreciever trigger when a site gets created on a site collection

Comment: this is the error: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite'.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting this error because it worked for me. We have different scenarios for sure, i wrote the code against a custom list of type "Announcements" that i created and named "ListName" as above, then i added an out of the box web part that shows the list "ListName". In your case is the web part itself of type "Announcements" wich is different but both serve the same purpose in your scenario? The code is however written against my custom list "ListName" in my site collection and it depends on no conditions to run but whenever the feature is activated.

Comment: Expires Listname is named "Announcements" for me, and i typed that inside trygetlist parameter

Comment: Is your feature scoped to Site or Web?

Comment: Change the scope to Site and it should work.

Comment: I need to have the feature scoped as web

Comment: Then you have to instantiate the site with where you want to work and use the using() to dispose the web and site objects as you are not using the properties parameter anymore which usually takes care of disposing those objects:

Using(SPSite site = new SPSite(@"SiteCollectionUrl"))
{
using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
//Same code goes here.
}
}

Comment: SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList["ListName"]; made it work!

Comment: Good! Despite the strange syntax of getting the list with brackets and not parenthesis!